# Element Click Intercepted With Wait

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I have an active textbox that has an inactive textbox over it. In order to send keys, I have to click on the inactive text box, then send the text to the active one. I have been doing this and it works, but only sometimes. It is very common to get an ElementIntercepted exception, matter fact gets this more than it successfully being able to click on the item. Below is the html.

```html
<div class="step__field step__form__block" id="dob-field-inactive"> 
      <input name="dob-plain" class="step__input" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth (mm / dd / yyyy)" autocomplete="off"> 
      <input name="dob-format" type="hidden" value="MDY"> 
      <span class="step__field__indicator"></span> 
</div>

<div class="step__field--date step__form__block phantom" id="dob-field-active"> 
    <input name="dob-month" class="step__input--date--mm" type="number" placeholder="mm" min="1" max="12" data-maxlength="2" value="" autocomplete="bday-month"> 
    <span class="step__input--date-separator">/</span> 
    <input name="dob-day" class="step__input--date--dd" type="number" placeholder="dd" min="1" max="31" data-maxlength="2" value="" autocomplete="bday-day"> <span class="step__input--date-separator">/</span>
     <input name="dob-year" class="step__input--date--yyyy" type="number" placeholder="yyyy" min="1900" max="2021" data-maxlength="4" value="" autocomplete="bday-year"> 
    <span class="step__field__indicator"></span> 
</div>
```

Here is my code,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 400);
driver.Manage().Window.Size = size;

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://account.battle.net/creation/flow/creation-full");

//click on inactive textbox to activate the active one
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("dob-plain"))).Click(); //ClickIntercepted
                
                
                //enter Month
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("01"))).SendKeys(month.ToString());
                
                //enter Day
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("01"))).SendKeys(day.ToString());
               
                //enter Year
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("1993"))).SendKeys(year.ToString());
```

This is the code I found to work best. Using javascript executor doesn't work at all. Actions doesn't work either. Maybe I am just not doing this correctly? Thank you to anyone who can provide some knowledge.

Comment: Strange the same code works just fine in my local.

Comment: Try running it more than once. I run around 10 threads of this and about 60% will fail. A friend of mine tried and it didn't work at all. Failed 100% of the time.

Comment: The only difference between him and I is he is in another country, but the html was the exact same.

Comment: Not sure I am trying from India,  and it worked, I tried for like 3-4 times

Comment: That is really strange. Is there any other way that would possibly have a higher success rate?

Comment: make automation screen in full screen everytime you run, along with explicit wait try to put sleep for like 1 secs or so

Comment: Alright. I have the screen size set to `200, 400` due to my users running around 5-30 threads at a time. My current wait is 10 seconds. I updated the code above to give more of an exact representation of my exact driver settings.

Answer (score 0):

An element being visible isn't enough. The element must be *interactable* — something you can click on. Just change your ExpectedConditions method call to `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(...)`:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("dob-plain")))
    .Click();
               
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("01")))
    .SendKeys(month.ToString());
                
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("01")))
    .SendKeys(day.ToString());
               
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("1993")))
    .SendKeys(year.ToString());
```

This works even if you need to type text into a text field.